# Catching Illegal Start of String in a list

Tags: error-handling, prolog

If I have a list `[1,2,3,]` and use it in the following:

`append([0],[1,2,3,],X)`

I will get an error because of the extra comma:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal start of term
ERROR: append([0],[1,2,3
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: ,],Stack) .
```

Is there a way to catch this error and make it fail with `false`?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? In what context? After all, the behavior of producing above error looks perfect to me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the extra comma. What purpose does it serve?

Simply by removing the comma, the program runs correctly:

```
1 ?- append([0],[1,2,3],X).
X = [0, 1, 2, 3].
```